# ggplot2 plot raw data for rare subgroups and boxplots for common subgroups

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Box plots can be handy to summarize continuous data, however, boxplots for rare  subgroups (n<10) are not always helpful. I was wondering if it would be possible to replace a boxplot with the raw data points in a grouped boxplot for those groups that are rare?

Example:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy))
p + geom_boxplot()
```

Produces a box plot of hwy (continuous) by each class (car type). However, looking at the frequencies for each class, we see that there are only 5 2seaters and 11 minivans. Instead of the box plot for 2seaters and minivans I'd like to see the raw data (points, potentially jittered), but keep the box plot for the other groups that meet the artificially set minimum sample size (eg n=20).

```
table(mpg$class)

   2seater    compact    midsize    minivan     pickup subcompact        suv       
         5         47         41         11         33         35         62
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how this can be done. You can change the value from 20 to whatever you like.

```r
# loading the needed libraries
library(tidyverse)

# adding a new column containing count information
(mpg <- mpg %>%
    dplyr::group_by(.data = ., class) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(.data = ., n = dplyr::n()))
#> # A tibble: 234 x 12
#> # Groups:   class [7]
#>    manufacturer model displ  year   cyl trans drv     cty   hwy fl    class
#>    <chr>        <chr> <dbl> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>
#>  1 audi         a4      1.8  1999     4 auto~ f        18    29 p     comp~
#>  2 audi         a4      1.8  1999     4 manu~ f        21    29 p     comp~
#>  3 audi         a4      2    2008     4 manu~ f        20    31 p     comp~
#>  4 audi         a4      2    2008     4 auto~ f        21    30 p     comp~
#>  5 audi         a4      2.8  1999     6 auto~ f        16    26 p     comp~
#>  6 audi         a4      2.8  1999     6 manu~ f        18    26 p     comp~
#>  7 audi         a4      3.1  2008     6 auto~ f        18    27 p     comp~
#>  8 audi         a4 q~   1.8  1999     4 manu~ 4        18    26 p     comp~
#>  9 audi         a4 q~   1.8  1999     4 auto~ 4        16    25 p     comp~
#> 10 audi         a4 q~   2    2008     4 manu~ 4        20    28 p     comp~
#> # ... with 224 more rows, and 1 more variable: n <int>

# plot
ggplot(data = mpg, mapping = aes(x = class, y = hwy, color = class)) +
  # plotting jittered points
  geom_jitter(size = 3, alpha = 0.5, width = 0.15) +
  # adding boxplots only for class with more than a certain count value
  geom_boxplot(data = dplyr::filter(.data = mpg, n > 20), alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-08-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Comment: There is no need to prefix `dplyr` methods with `dplyr::` as you already load the `tidyverse` packages.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Yeah, it might be redundant but I still think it’s a good code hygiene practice.

Comment: I totally disagree because this creates unnecessary clutter and reduced readability. But each to their own (coding style).

Comment: Additionally to quote Hadley [on the use of `::` in function calls](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html): *"This [i.e. avoiding `::`] also has a small performance benefit, because :: adds approximately 5 µs to function evaluation time."*

Answer (score 1):

This solution only plots the points for the small dataset sizes (as requested) and box plots only for the larger classes:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

min_n <- 20

mpg %>% 
  group_by(class) %>% 
  mutate(class_count = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(class, hwy, color = class)) +
  geom_jitter(data = . %>% filter(class_count < min_n)) +
  geom_boxplot(data = . %>% filter(class_count >= min_n))
```

[image]

Something you might also want to have a look at is `geom_violin` which adds more information about the data distribution and I find more informative than a boxplot (and you can have both :) ):

```
mpg %>% 
  group_by(class) %>% 
  mutate(class_count = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(class, hwy, color = class)) +
  geom_jitter(data = . %>% filter(class_count < min_n)) +
  geom_violin(data = . %>% filter(class_count >= min_n), scale = "count") +
  geom_boxplot(data = . %>% filter(class_count >= min_n), width = 0.1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are excellent when the factors of the x-axis are unordered, however this sort of filtering will cause the order of x-axis factors to be lost. Instead include the `drop=False` option for `scale_x_discrete()`:

```
  mpg %>% 
  group_by(class) %>% 
  mutate(class_count = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(class, hwy, color = class)) +
  geom_jitter(data = . %>% filter(class_count < min_n)) +
  geom_boxplot(data = . %>% filter(class_count >= min_n))+
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)
```